# inconsistent behavior with future defined as a global variable when trying to call get method on a future object

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, future

It is a very simple multithreaded-programming.
I am trying to share *vect* between all the threads but I have come across a very weird issue and it is:  when I declare the *vect* as a global variable the code crashes but soon I declare inside the function func as a local variable, it works perfectly. I spent a lot of time debugging and I found something weird that doesn't make sense to me. when very first future object is moved in the vect, on the item.get(), it is supposed to wait till a value returned from a corresponding function and its status should be pending, but surprisingly its status changes to 'empty' and this only happens for the very first object but the rest are pending and I don't understand it! Soon I move that 'vect' variable inside the function 'func' and when the first object is moved in the *vect*, it will remain pending along with others which is how it is supposed to work! Any ideas on this weird issue when a global variable is defined?

P.S. : I know it might be a very stupid example or question but I am new and I'm learning about how to use async and future and how to debug a code in multithreaded-programming.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
std::vector<std::future<int>> vect;
int  func(int counter)
{
    
    
    if (counter > 4)
    {
        return counter;
    }
    std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &func, counter + 1);

    vect.push_back(std::move(fut));
    std::for_each(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [&](auto& item)

        {

            int result = item.get();
            std::cout << "result: " << result << '\n';

        });

    return counter;

}



int main()
{
    int counter = 1;
    std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &func, counter);
    fut.wait();
    //int result = fut.get();
    //std::cout << "result: " << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If all of your threads are modifying `vect`, and you do not have those modifications protected by some sort of thread synchronization technique, then your code has Undefined Behavior.

Comment: But it is a recursive call, threads aren't spawned at the same time.

Comment: even without the problem Nathan just pointed out, I don't see how this could work. The first call starts the second call and waits for the second call to end. The second call starts the third call and waits for the second and third calls to both end. Deadlock.

Comment: @Sam doesn't std::async(std::launch::async start a new thread?

Comment: @Sam You still have the same problem.  You spawn thread 1, thread one spawns thread 2 and the goes on to modify the vector.  While it is doing that thread 2 spawns thread 3 and could catch up to thread 1 and modify the vector at the same time.

Comment: @ user253751 I was thinking the same when I found that the issue could be because of race condition. Can't we use recursive lock?

Comment: @NathanOliver. you're right. My issue was why first future object on 'item.get()' changes its status to 'empty' while nothing hasn't returned! you see what I am saying? could this nonsense behavior be the result of race condition?

Comment: Once you have UB in your code anything can happen.  Fix the UB and if you still get the issue then you know you have a logic issue somewhere.

Comment: @ NathanOliver . Right, Thank you so much. soon I moved the vect variable into the function, the code works well so no race condition and no UB happens! I didn't know UB could cause such issue too!